# Trying to do dumpRAM using python

Tags: python

i'm trying to dump RAM for my virtualbox using python script but it give me an error and I just can it solve it 
this my code :

```
import os
from struct import *
import optparse
import random
import string

machine_name = "OSC-2016"

def dump_ram():

    output_file = "test.elf"
    ram_file_name = "ram.bin"

    dump_cmd = "vboxmanage debugvm %s dumpvmcore --filename %s" %(machine_name, output_file)

    os.system(dump_cmd)

    popen_cmd = "readelf --program-headers %s |grep -m1 -A1 LOAD" %(output_file) 

    file_info = os.popen(popen_cmd).read()
     #print file_info

    file_info = " ".join(file_info.split()) #remove duplicate spaces

    file_info = file_info.split() #create a list by splitting on spaces

    ram_start = int(file_info[1], 16)
    ram_size = int(file_info[4], 16)
    print "RAM SIZE is ", ram_size
    ram = open(output_file, "rb").read()[ram_start:ram_start + ram_size]

    ram_file_var = open(ram_file_name, "wb")
    ram_file_var.write(ram)
    ram_file_var.close()


def main():

    dump_ram()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the error as it shown

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/dumpRAM.py", line 42, in <module> main()
   File "C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/dumpRAM.py", line 39, in main dump_ram()
   File "C:/Users/ABC/Desktop/dumpRAM.py", line 27, in dump_ram
   ram_start = int(file_info[1], 16)
   IndexError: list index out of range
```

WHAT TO DO ?
it for my homework in operating system course and tomorrow  is the final day , so I will be so helpful if you help , and i'm writing this cuz the stack overflow won't publish my question cuz it have too much code and less details and it requiring more details hhhhhhhh

Comment: Obviously, `file_info[1]` is `out of range`. How does it look (comment that print statement back in). Also, joining and re-splitting a list of strings is redundant.